# Difference between rospy.Service and rospy.Serviceproxy

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
When I'm learning the concepts about ROS service from this web :http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services, I was confused by these two similar functions rospy.Service and rospy.Serviceproxy. From my understanding , both functions do the same things as they pass the same arguments. Hope someone can address my question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355144/difference-between-rospy.service-and-rospy.serviceproxy/) by [hammerli](https://answers.ros.org/users/55858/hammerli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @hammerli,

1. The`rospy.Service`directive returns an Service instance with a callback for the node to provide a service communication.
2. The `rospy.ServiceProxy`directive returns a callable instance that is used to perform a request to the server client.

To provide a simple [example](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) I will use the main tutorial about this paradigm of communication.

Let us say that you have two nodes: Node A provides a service with the name `add_integers` to sum two integer numbers, so it needs to use `rospy.Service` to let ROS know that it provides this kind of service for anyone willing to compute the sum of two integers. Meanwhile, Node B, that struggles to compute the sum of two numbers, suddenly realised that it can use the implementation provided by Node A and solve its problem. In that case, Node B, will use a `rospy.ServiceProxy` instance refering to the `add_integers` Service to request Node A with the sum of two integer that he provides. With that particular set up you have a Server/Client architecture where one node processes requests (Node A) and another one just requests things (Node B).

I hope that helps you to understand better both directives.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hammerli](https://answers.ros.org/users/55858/hammerli/) on 2020-06-22**:
Thanks for your explanation, it really helps!